# MVC Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Based on my research, I have tried an autocomplete code for MVC C# and it works. Here's the code:

For the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Users").autocomplete({
        source: function(request,response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/AutoCompleteUsers",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.Name, value: item.ID };
                    }))

                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
```

In view:

```
Enter Name: @Html.TextBox("Employees")
<input type="submit" id="GetEmployees" value="Submit"/>
```

In controller:

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteUsers(string term)
{
    var result = (from r in db.Users
    where r.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())
    select new { r.Name, r.ID }).Distinct();
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My question is:

I want to know how to get the corresponding ID and put it in input field of the form so that the ID will be included in the form for submission. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a `model property` for the Text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.Hidden("EmployeeId")
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Users").autocomplete({
    source: function(request,response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/AutoCompleteUsers",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.Name, value: item.ID };
                }))

            }
        })
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
      event.preventdefault().
      $("#EmployeeId").val(ui.item.value);
      $("#Employees").val(ui.item.label);
    },
    messages: {
        noResults: "", results: ""
    }
});
})
```

Comment: I tried to send it in the form and pass the "Employees" to action that will show the corresponding ID to display the ID but the value is 0. My action accepts Employees as parameter int since its value is the ID. I queried it to table and looped it. I used Viewbag to display the name of that certain ID and return to view. Problem is the value of #Employees is 0.

Comment: see the edited answer. make sure to correctly map the #EmployeeId in controller action

Comment: I already got it but whenever I chose one from the textbox field it will be replaced by the ID int the Employee ID field. Why?

Comment: I already got the answer, I just added: event.preventdefault().. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`select`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) property of autocomplete and tell it what to do when user selects an item from autocomplete:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#Employees").val(ui.item.value); //setting id in Employees TextBox

    }
```

More better would be to set employee name in TextBox and set id in a hidden field and on form post retrieve id from hidden field:

```
Enter Name: @Html.TextBox("Employees")
<input id="EmployeeId" type="hidden"/>
<input type="submit" id="GetEmployees" value="Submit"/>
```

and then:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#Employees").val(ui.item.label); 
            $("#EmployeeId").val(ui.item.value);

        }
```

### select( event, ui ):

> > Triggered when an item is selected from the menu. The default action is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected item.

Comment: Thanks for that. It shows the corresponding ID of each name in the EmployeeID but the textbox field is being replaced by the id once I chose one of the list. Why so?

Comment: did'nt got you what you said